# Chat between Mac and Ubuntu

Tags: mac, compatibility, instant-messaging

I need to send files quickly via a chat program between Ubuntu and Mac OS X.

Most chat programs, including WhatsApp and Viber, don't allow self messages.

Is there a program I can use?

Comment: I can send files to other users using `hexchat` (inc. myself I guess too), I suspect it's possible using any IRC client (which is a chat program), but 'chat' is a very wide area & I think your question is more related to protocols.  *Note: sending files in IRC will reveal my real IP address nullifying my Ubuntu cloak, so there are costs to it that may matter*

Comment: What is a good IRC client? Basically hexchat?

Comment: Also, can you send files?

Comment: I've already stated I use `hexchat` , though I've got `quassel` on another box (which is leaner on that environment).  The best for you only you can decide... I'm using `hexchat` as I have for years as it's easier to move my configs (hidden keys etc) from box to box, easier than switching to a possibly better program.  I'd like to move to `irssi` though  (which won't suit everyone; to allow me to use the one connection from different boxes instead of my current different connections)

Comment: Yes I can send files in `hexchat` & `quassel` (I haven't done it in `irssi` but I suspect so too)  but as stated it will reveal my real IP address (sent files file go direct to other person so my 'cloak' is void to the person i send the file to)   *Most users don't use or have cloaks anyway... so it may not matter*

Comment: Is there a good guide for send files in hexchat? You use something called dcc?

Comment: I right click on the user I want in the room, a menu appears and I select "Send file".  It's not difficult (as easy as opening a private chat with that person, in fact *send file* is just below *Open dialog..* option).  The md5sum of the file is sent along with meta data of the file... The end-user has to ACCEPT before the file is sent (*which I think is good!*)

Comment: Ok epic, I didn’t realise you could right click the usernames. I was looking in the menu bar.

Comment: One thing I am having problems with, is I can accept files from Mac on Ubuntu, but it doesn't work the other way around. I send a file to Mac, and the thing says "Connect" but the accept button is greyed out. Then the connection times out.

Comment: I'd check your permissions/preferences/settings. Some clients default to disabling this feature (dangerous for end-users; malware etc esp. windows where malware is more of a risk)  by default; needing a checkbox being clicked to enable it before it can be used. This is guess though

Comment: It just has some random bug. It won't accept, and resume says the file doesn't exist. You can click accept now, but it does nothing. Then the thing times out. I went through all the settings and have auto accept on. It works fine sending to Ubuntu. I'll try and ask a question about it. Thank you anyway, I'll get it working.

Comment: I suspect your issue is on your mac end; ie. your mac software which I won't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can send files to other users using `hexchat` (*inc myself*), I suspect it's possible using any IRC client (which is a chat program), but 'chat' is a very wide area & I think your question is more related to protocols.

Note: sending files in IRC will reveal my real IP address nullifying my Ubuntu cloak, so there are costs to it that may matter

In `hexchat` I right click the user I want to send a file to, a menu appears and I select "*Send file*". It's not difficult (*as easy as opening a private chat with that person, in fact send file is just below Open dialog.. option*).

The md5sum of the file is sent along with meta data of the file... The end-user has to ACCEPT before the file is sent (which I think is good!).  If the other user doesn't accept in a certain time, timeout occurs & send is aborted.

I just sent a file from this my primary workstation to another box using a 'live' Ubuntu system (a QA-test that happened to be nearby; ie. to a system that wasn't even installed).  This is not really a feature of `hexchat`, but more the protocol used by IRC.

*I use `hexchat` as example as it's my primary client*